# Authenticity of a Hadith regarding the Prophet SAW & Ali RA being in a state of janaba in the mosque

Tags: hadith, authenticity

> Narrated by Abu Sa’id (ra) from the Prophet (Peace be upon him) who said to Ali (ra): O Ali, it is not allowed for anyone to be in state of seminal impurity in this mosque, “**except for me and you**” [Sunan Tirimdhi, Volume No. 1, Page No. 535 where Imam Tirimdhi declared it “Hassan”]

According to [this](https://www.dar-alifta.org/Foreign/ViewFatwa.aspx?ID=10509), there are ahadith which state that those in a state seminal impurity, not just the Prophet SAW or Ali RA, are allowed to be in mosques. Is this particular hadith truly authentic?

Comment: https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/49/124

Comment: Not anyone BUT ONLY Ali (RA) and Prophet Mohammad (PBUH), and yes this Hadith is certified as authentic by many many scholars, and Sunni and Shia both agree on this Hadith.

Comment: You need to read the question again carefully. Go to the link.

Comment: @Afiq I did go to the link but it only talks about Ali (RA) and Prophet Mohammad (PBUH) no one else at all.

Comment: Read the first few paragraphs

Comment: @SyedMohammadSannan - Yes, dear. Kindly do tell me who has classified it as authentic because my sources show that Imam Tirmidhi has classified it as Hasan-Ghareeb narration. Thanks!

Comment: @Afiq - Are you satisfied with my answer?

Comment: It makes some sense

Comment: @Afiq - Some time ago you asked a question about Prophets taking booty in the Bible. What are your conclusions about that question?

Comment: I just wanted clarification for a supposed contradiction. The Prophet SAW said that no Prophet before him SAW consumed spoils of war. We can put aside the verses concerning Moses AS because they're unclear whether or not the Prophet AS had a share from the booty. However David AS took a crown from a gentile king.

Answer (score 1):

Salam'alaikum Brother!

The narration you cited has been declared "Da'if" by Darussalam. I think they did this because one of the narrators is Salim Bin Abi Hafsh (A Shi'ah narrator) and he has been declared weak by some scholars, including Imam Bukhari. Imam Bukhari writes in Tarikh Al-Kabir:-

> سالم بن أبي حفصة أخو إبراهيم الكوفي عن منذر الثوري قال لي عمرو بن علي
> سمعت عليا يقول نا يحيى بن سعيد نا بن عيينة نا سالم بن أبي حفصة أبو
> يونس قال يحيى لو كان سالم لم أكتبه

**However, some scholars have accepted this narration.**

For example, it was graded as Hasan-Gharib by Abu Isa Tirmidhi:-

[image]

It has been explained in Fath Ul Bari here about this narration in the commentary of Jam'i At- Tirmidhi:-

[image]